# How To Disable Backdrop Menu Dismiss - Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm having trouble finding documentation on this.

In Ionic, the menu has functionality where if you click on the backdrop, the menu dismisses. So basically click anywhere except the menu and the menu goes away. I want to disable this functionality so users can interact with items below the backdrop.

I've tried disabling pointer events on the backdrop and the menu, but the dismiss still seems to occur. Any thoughts?

---

Interesting discovery; the menu dismiss functionality actually looks like it might be on the ion-content. Which leads to an issue:

- I want users to be able to interact with the content with ion-content without dismissing the menu.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this helped:

```
ion-menu {
  pointer-events: none;
}

ion-menu > * {
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the sample code how you can do this in your ionic application.

```
    import { Platform, MenuController } from 'ionic-angular';

// ... Other code

  constructor(menuCtrl: MenuController /* ... other code ...*/)

// ... Other code

  let menu = menuCtrl.get();

  menu.swipeEnable(false); // Disable drag to open/close

  // Override default behaviour of closing the menu on 
  // content or backdrop click
  menu['onBackdropClick'] = () => {
    // No-op  
  };

  menu.ionOpen.subscribe(() => {
    // When the menu is open ...

    // Remove Ionic's CSS rules for menu-content-open class that restricts 
    // mouse events on ion-nav
    menu.getContentElement().classList.remove("menu-content-open");

    // Reduce the size of the content pane so that it does not
    // overflow off the screen
    menu.getContentElement().style.width = 
      `calc(100% - ${menu.getMenuElement().clientWidth}px)`;
  });

  menu.ionClose.subscribe(() => {
    // When the menu is closed ...

    // Restore the size of the content pane
    menu.getContentElement().style.width = '';
  });
```

I made a stackblitz project you can check it out. You can check it out from [here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/multi-level-side-menu-ionic)